# php getopts() hybrid first parameter invalidating remaining parameters

Tags: php

I have the following in `my-file.php`:

```
$short_options = "r:";
$long_options = ["root:"];
$options = getopt($short_options, $long_options);
print_r($options);
```

These all work:

```bash
php my-file.php -r foo
php my-file.php -r=foo
php my-file.php -rfoo
php my-file.php --root foo
php my-file.php --root=foo
```

BUT, if I add an intended `<filename>` like this:

```
php my-file.php <filename> -r foo    #or any of the above
```

`r` is not read

the first parameter would be understood by everyone to always be the file name.  How do I fix this?

Comment: That's not how getopt works. <filename> needs a key too, for example like this: _php my-file.php -f <filename> -r foo_

Comment: That's quite sad

Answer (score 0):

To handle both options and non-option arguments, you can modify your script to first process the options using `getopt()` and then handle any remaining arguments separately like the following

```
<?php

$short_options = "r:";
$long_options = ["root:"];
$options = getopt($short_options, $long_options, $optind);

print_r($options);

// Get non-option arguments
$non_option_args = array_slice($argv, $optind);

// Assuming the first non-option argument is the filename
$filename = $non_option_args[0] ?? null;

if ($filename) {
    echo "Filename: " . $filename . PHP_EOL;
}
```